# Adding elements to JPanel but they aren't displaying

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to add a complex set of elements in a JPanel, lay them out according to how many columns are returned - and display it in a new panel which is generated on a button click

I'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is.
Replacing other text elements within the header panel works absolutely fine, but can't see why my generated code just isn't being added to the panel (or more likely - the panel just isn't being displayed in a way that's accessible)

```
            My JPanel output code - 
            private JPanel getOutput() throws BadIdent {

    short[] HDformats = { HDformat, Audformat };
    short[] SDformats = { SDformat, Audformat };
    List poolInfo;
    List freeSpaceHD = null;
    List freeSpaceSD = null;
    System.out.println(man.getZoneNumberName());
    // System.out.println(man.getPoolInfo());
    poolInfo = man.getPoolInfo();
    List poolSpace = man.getPoolSpace();
    if ((Short) HDformat != null) {
        freeSpaceHD = man.getFreeSpace(HDformats);
    }
    if ((Short) SDformat != null) {
        freeSpaceSD = man.getFreeSpace(SDformats);
    }
    JPanel content_panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(poolInfo.size(), 4));
    JLabel[] PoolInfoLabel = new JLabel[poolInfo.size()];
    JLabel[] PoolSpaceLabel = new JLabel[poolInfo.size()];
    JLabel[] PoolSpaceHDLabel = new JLabel[poolInfo.size()];
    JLabel[] PoolSpaceSDLabel = new JLabel[poolInfo.size()];
    JPanel[] PoolInfo = new JPanel[poolInfo.size()];
    // GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPoolInfo[] = new
    // GridBagConstraints[poolInfo
    // .size()];
    // JLabel[] PoolInfoLabel = new JLabel[poolInfo.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < poolInfo.size(); i++) {
        PoolInfoLabel[i] = new JLabel();
        PoolSpaceLabel[i] = new JLabel();
        PoolSpaceHDLabel[i] = new JLabel();
        PoolSpaceSDLabel[i] = new JLabel();
        PoolInfoLabel[i].setText((String) poolInfo.get(i));
        System.out.println(poolInfo.get(i));
        PoolSpaceLabel[i].setText((String) poolSpace.get(i));
        PoolSpaceHDLabel[i].setText((String) freeSpaceHD.get(i));
        PoolSpaceSDLabel[i].setText((String) freeSpaceSD.get(i));

        //
        // System.out.println(PoolInfoLabel[i].getText());

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < PoolInfoLabel.length; i++) {
        PoolInfo[i] = new JPanel();
        PoolInfo[i].add(PoolInfoLabel[i]);
        PoolInfo[i].add(PoolSpaceLabel[i]);
        PoolInfo[i].add(PoolSpaceHDLabel[i]);
        PoolInfo[i].add(PoolSpaceSDLabel[i]);
        System.out.println(PoolSpaceLabel[i].getText());
        System.out.println(PoolSpaceSDLabel[i].getText());
        System.out.println(PoolSpaceHDLabel[i].getText());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < PoolInfo.length; i++) {
        content_panel.add(PoolInfo[i]);
    }
    return content_panel;
}
```

Button code to add and change elements in the panel and frame (frame is the main display, panel is the header, located in NORTH border layout. 
The three comboboxes are added and displayed correctly, and I'm using much the same mechanism to generate and display them as I'm using in the getOutput() function

```
    JButton ButtonSubmit = new JButton("Connect");
    ButtonSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                man.ManagerConnect(ISAHostName.getText(), null);
                // System.out.println(man.getZoneNumberName());
                ZoneNumName.setText(man.getZoneNumberName());
                AudFormat = getAudCombo();
                HDVidFormat = getHDCombo();
                SDVidFormat = getSDCombo();
                panel.add(HDVidFormat, gbc_HDVidFormat);
                panel.add(SDVidFormat, gbc_SDVidFormat);
                panel.add(AudFormat, gbc_AudFormat);
                btnFormatButton.setEnabled(true);
                frame.repaint();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    panel.add(ButtonSubmit, gbc_ButtonSubmit);
    btnFormatButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                JPanel content_panel = getOutput();
                frame.getContentPane().add(content_panel,
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);
            } catch (BadIdent e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
    panel.add(btnFormatButton, gbc_btnNewButton);
```

For reference - get HD format combobox

```
private JPanel getHDCombo() {
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    combo.setMaximumRowCount(10);
    final Map<String, Integer> map = man.HDVidFormats();
    Collection<String> keys = map.keySet();
    Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String key = it.next();
        combo.addItem(key);
    }
    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox combo = (JComboBox) e.getSource();
            String key = (String) combo.getSelectedItem();
            int format = map.get(key);
            System.out.println(format);
            HDformat = (short) format;
        }
    });
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    panel.add(combo);
    return panel;
}
```

I'm sure it's simple, but I honestly can't see why the panel isn't being added
Apologies for the code - it's been a few years since I wrote any GUI code from scratch in Java

Comment: Did you use a `null` layout for the frame, I mean `frame.setLayout(null)`? AND Did you added your panel to the frame in the constructro

Comment: Consider making a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for better help, there is too many code out there

Comment: Try adding `frame.getContentPane().invalidate();`, `frame.getContentPane().validate();` and `frame.getContentPane().repaint()` after `frame.getContentPane().add(content_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

Comment: Also, you don't need `frame.getContentPane()`, `frame.add` will delegate to `getContentPane()` for you

Comment: Ok - I added my content_panel to panel (which is the header)
Although unforgivably messy, the content is there - so it looks like it's a bounding issue, or an issue with adding the content_panel directly to the frame.
I might add a new panel to the frame, and embed the panel into that - but don't hold out much hope - the repaint on the frame appears to set the size of content_panel effectively to '0x0'

Comment: Hi Azad - I'm using a border layout for the frame, so that works nicely for the header panel (which I will rename to make it more clear) - I'm trying to make the content_panel the center layout in the border layout, to fill the whole block nicely

Answer (score 0):

set your layout to null with `frame.setLayout(null);`

do what MadProgrammer said

> Try adding frame.getContentPane().invalidate();, frame.getContentPane().validate(); and frame.getContentPane().repaint() after frame.getContentPane().add(content_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER) –  [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) Aug 29 at 0:42

and in regards to your second problem add it like this

```
frame.add(*jpanel here*, BorderLayout.CENTER);
*jpanel*.setBounds(width,height,x,y); //check up on this one. i think the param might be backwards
```

the set bounds should move your jpanel to the location and set its bounds based on height and width.